# Lexicon is ignored in SSML using MS cognitive speech service

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I try to use a lexicon but the TTS service ignores it.

This is my lexicon xml file:

```
<lexicon xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/01/pronunciation-lexicon http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/CR-pronunciation-lexicon-20071212/pls.xsd" 
    version="1.0" 
    xml:lang="de-DE"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/01/pronunciation-lexicon">
    <lexeme>
        <grapheme>Achsöl</grapheme>
        <phoneme>aks øːl</phoneme>
    </lexeme>
</lexicon>
```

I serve the file using a simple python server and ngrok

```
python3 -m http.server 80
ngrok http 80
```

In my c# code I create SSML which looks like this when sent to the TTS service:

```
<speak version="1.0"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
       xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts"    
       xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml"
       xml:lang="de-DE">
    <voice name="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (de-DE, KatjaNeural)">
        <lexicon uri="https://xyz.ngrok.io/Lexikon.xml" />
        Achsöl
    </voice>
</speak>
```

But the TTS service ignores my lexicon. I've checked that the file is accessible from internet.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the SSML work when you use it in Azure speech studio's [audio content creation tool](https://speech.microsoft.com/portal/456d9cafaf984e828e43ac54358d637b/audiocontentcreation)? I would recommend to debug the SSML or use plain text to build your audio file and use that SSML in this code with the SDK.